# Asterisk - Send and and recieve SMS to mobile phones

Tags: asterisk, sms-gateway

I have an Asterisk that has several employees connected to it. each person has their own DID and they can make/receive calls to/from PSTN - No problem there

I am looking for a viable option, to connect these users to a SMS gateway, however here is the trick: I need each user to send SMS to outside mobile with their DID number as FROM, also receive the replied SMS on their phone (outgoing SMS with a return Path)
As far as volume, goes, I am looking long term, so I need high volume, cost is no issue.

Most options on SMS gateways look as they send out SMS as a bulk

Answer (score 0):

SMS technology is belongs to mobile networks. So if you don't get your DIDs from mobile operator (by gsm-gateway for example), I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It is possible. To add an update here. There are DID providers that give you SMS enabled DIDs. they have their own gateway, so you have to develop an API to talk to the their gateway to pass / receive SMS. not a bad system in general